# Need Sencha Touch 2.0 MVC tutorials

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am a new bee to sencha touch 2.0.0,i want tutorials that explains some login system and crud examples so that i will grasp over the sencha touch . Can someone help me in this perspective?

Comment: although it is very helpfull tutorial.   http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-3/                                  but i want more tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but your answer is a little bit too wide to be answered exactly.

But when I was a newbie to Sencha Touch 2, I did this way and found out that it's quite fast to learn. You can take it as a reference:

- Understand how Model and Store works. This is really important as the APIs for them in ST2 are much different from ST1. Pay more attention to these methods: `add` (creating new records), `find` and `set` (for locating & updating records), `remove` (for deleting records).
- Login is basically sending the values of a `Ext.form.Panel`. Also read its documention, there's already an example there.

**Conclusion**: You should try to read and write your own code first. If you encounter errors and cannot find anyways to fix them, come back here, show off what you've done and I will try to help you. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for you reply. how much time you have taken to become a professional. i am trying my best. i will do as you suggest me and will got you soon.

Comment: honestly, I'm not a pro in Sencha Touch, just an intermediate user :) I've just worked with ST1 for 3 months and 2 months for ST2 :) Nearly forgot all APIs of ST1 since they're completely changed in ST2 :-))

Comment: this is the basic reason that sencha touch is not a stable still as it is updating from st2.0 to st2.1. i am starting st since last two days. as i am working with php.

Comment: yes, but app structure will stay solid (with MVC pattern), so considering what you wanted to do, I highly agree that you should learn ST2 right now. Forget all about ST1 with ugly & weird code, bad performance, a nightmare, I swear :(